# ¿Event after the end of delivering the response to the user?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Well basically what I need is to delete some files from the storage folder, but I want that to happen every time a request is finished.

I have already created an event and a listener that is responsible for doing that, which is called before doing the return in the controller. But since some exception may happen, the event is obviously not going to be launched.

I need that to always run regardless of whether an exception occurs or not.

The laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/lifecycle#application-events talks about it but it is in version 4.2 and that does not have the current version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`AfterMiddleware`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware#defining-middleware):

> This middleware would perform its task **after the request is handled by the application**:

```
class AfterMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        // Perform action
        return $response;
    }
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware#defining-middleware